# Symfony app, the content is displaying twice

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.1

First question here. 
I'm developing a login page, and I can't figure out why my login form shows twice. I double checked the twig files and the routes and I don't see what could be causing it.

I'm using php server so I'm in the dev env, and I think what is happening is that my debug bar is being replaced with actual page causing to display the content twice. The debugger bar is not showing. I searched on google and I saw that they are mentioning something about the body tag not being closed, so I checked that too. Still noting. I checked if some other file is also calling login template. Nothing... Any suggestions?

Here is an image, which is worth than a thousand words.

Thanks

[image shows the login page showing twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXIDy.png)

In addition, here is the code that I'm using, which is straight from symfony's documentation:

Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="security_login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

Securit.yml

```
providers:
    app_user_prov:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - cas_authenticator
```

login twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
{% if error %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="bg-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="margin-top:35px;">
            <img style="border:none;" src="loreipsum.png" width="200">
            <br />&nbsp;<br />
            <form action="{{ path("security_login") }}" method="post" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username or email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Base twig file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Administration{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymo

        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />

    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1 class="text-left">
                <img style="border:none;" src="loremipsum.jpg" width="200">
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3 class="text-right">&nbsp;<br/>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide us some code

Comment: The code is actually from symfony's documentation. Same structure, same code

Comment: Show us base.html.twig too, please.

Comment: @DFayet Added all the code

Comment: Interesting.. Can you access the url `/app_dev.php/_profiler` ? Do you see anything suspicious?

Comment: Are you using any unusual 3rd party bundles?  All I can think is that you have a render controller call somewhere in your twig templates.  Or maybe a rogue kernel listener trying to add a login form to every page.

Comment: First check if it working in build in php webserver.. If yes that mean your rewrite rules are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your login page have not public access:

```
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

So symfony show FOS Login first and when you authenticate user, redirect to the previous requested page /login

Comment: I do have the path and role set like you are suggesting: 
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }